# Cumulative histogram over the frames

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scipy, data-analysis

I had normalized data of histogram stored in separate files. How do I plot the cumulative histogram?

```
{Frame 1}(filename)
-1.114060000000000050e-01 0.000000000000000000e+00
-1.140599999999999947e-02 0.000000000000000000e+00
8.859400000000000608e-02 0.000000000000000000e+00
1.885940000000000394e-01 0.000000000000000000e+00
2.885940000000000172e-01 0.000000000000000000e+00
3.885939999999999950e-01 9.999999999999991118e+00
4.885940000000000838e-01 0.000000000000000000e+00
5.885940000000000616e-01 0.000000000000000000e+00
6.885940000000000394e-01 0.000000000000000000e+00 
7.885940000000000172e-01 0.000000000000000000e+00
```

Can someone give me idea how do I proceed? I look https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.cumfreq.html but didn't get any clue.

I used following code:

```
hist, bin_edges = n.histogram(a, density = True)
```

to generate this histogram files(normalized).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `plt.hist`, which has both the argument `density` (which normalizes) and `cumulative`, to plot the cumulative histogram:

```
plt.hist(a, density = True ,cumulative=True)
plt.show()
```